# Breeze and Knockout not binding correctly

Tags: javascript, binding, knockout.js, breeze, knockout-2.0

I was trying a sample using breeze and knockout

```js
manager.executeQuery(query).then(function(result){
    console.log(result);    
    ko.applyBindings(result);
}).fail(function(e) {
    console.log(e); 
     alert(e);  
});
```

While printing in the console. I'm getting two objects in the path `data.XHR.result.responseJSON` and two objects in `data.results`

But in the view created as a result of knockout binding I'm getting the second set of value populated two times. (I have two set of values in the db)

NOTE: This code is working if I havent defined any metadata. Issue is in the scenario where I use metadata

metadata

```
var sample=sample||{};sample.metadata=
{
    "dataServices":[
        {
            "serviceName":"/sample",
            "hasServerMetadata":true,
            "jsonResultsAdapter":"webApi_default",
            "useJsonp":false
        }
    ],
    "structuralTypes":[
        {
            "shortName":"Employee",
            "autoGeneratedKeyType":"None",
            "defaultResourceName":"Employee",
            "dataProperties":[
                {
                    "name":"id",
                    "dataType":"MongoObjectId",
                    "isNullable":false,
                    "defaultValue":"",
                    "isPartOfKey":true,
                    "validators":[
                        {
                            "name":"required"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name":"name",
                    "dataType":"String",
                    "maxLength":100,
                    "validators":[
                        {
                            "maxLength":100,
                            "name":"maxLength"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name":"age",
                    "dataType":"String",
                    "maxLength":100,
                    "validators":[
                        {
                            "maxLength":100,
                            "name":"maxLength"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
       ], 
    "resourceEntityTypeMap":{
        "Employee":"Employee"
    }
};
```

Comment: Sounds like whatever you are using as a primary key is coming across the wire undefined.  Can you show your model?

Comment: There must be `ko.applyBindings(result.results)` I guess.

Comment: @f_martinez Its working if metadata is not defined

Comment: @PWKad You were right :) solved it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you have a primary key that is defined in your model and coming across the wire.  If you leave those values as null they will overwrite each other when breeze adds them to the cache and sees the keys are the same.